# Error while connecting to MYSQL through spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to MYSQL through the spark shell with the below code

```
val dataframe_mysql = sqlcontext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/universe").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "customer").option("user", "root").option("password", "PASSWORD").load()
```

I have the mysql connector jar. But I get the below error

```
error: error while loading package, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/execution/package.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains package object
execution error: error while loading QueryExecution, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class QueryExecution
error: error while loading package, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/package.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains package object plans
error: error while loading LogicalPlan, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/LogicalPlan.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class LogicalPlan
error: error while loading package, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/package.class)' has location not matching its contents: contains package object
encoders error: error while loading ExpressionEncoder, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder.class)' has location not matching its contents: contains class
ExpressionEncoder error: error while loading Expression, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression.class)' has location not matching its contents: contains class Expression
error: error while loading NamedExpression, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/NamedExpression.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class NamedExpression
error: error while loading DataFrameNaFunctions, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class
DataFrameNaFunctions error: error while loading
DataFrameStatFunctions, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameStatFunctions.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class
DataFrameStatFunctions error: error while loading TypedColumn, class
file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/TypedColumn.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class TypedColumn
error: error while loading package, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/function/package.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains package object
function error: error while loading ReduceFunction, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/function/ReduceFunction.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class ReduceFunction
error: error while loading KeyValueGroupedDataset, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class
KeyValueGroupedDataset error: error while loading MapFunction, class
file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/function/MapFunction.class)' has location not matching its contents: contains class MapFunction
error: error while loading Metadata, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class Metadata error:
error while loading FilterFunction, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FilterFunction.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class FilterFunction
error: error while loading MapPartitionsFunction, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/function/MapPartitionsFunction.class)' has location not matching its contents: contains class
MapPartitionsFunction error: error while loading FlatMapFunction,
class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class FlatMapFunction
error: error while loading ForeachFunction, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/function/ForeachFunction.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class ForeachFunction
error: error while loading ForeachPartitionFunction, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/function/ForeachPartitionFunction.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class
ForeachPartitionFunction error: error while loading StorageLevel,
class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/storage/StorageLevel.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class StorageLevel
error: error while loading CreateViewCommand, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/CreateViewCommand.class)' has location not matching its contents: contains class
CreateViewCommand error: error while loading DataFrameWriter, class
file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class DataFrameWriter
error: error while loading DataStreamWriter, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamWriter.class)' has location not matching its contents: contains class
DataStreamWriter error: error while loading SparkPlan, class file
'C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.4.3.jar(org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkPlan.class)'
has location not matching its contents: contains class SparkPlan
```

Comment: Can you show how do you start the spark-shell ?

Comment: `sqlcontext` to `sqlContext` maybe?